Is there a Jacobson congruence - the universal-algebraic generalization of the Jacobson ring.
What do you call the universal algebra generalization of the Jacobson ring and where can I read more about it?

This question is a follow-up to this question that I asked about an hour ago, more specifically this answer by Qiaochu Yuan and this comment by Noah Schweber.
The Jacobson radical is the intersection of all maximal ideals.
This has a natural translation to the universal algebra setting.
There's a 1:1 order-preserving map between ideals and congruences with both lattices ordered by inclusion. A larger ideal gives a coarser congruence, and a coarser congruence has more edges.
A maximal ideal in the ring setting is a maximal congruence in the universal algebra setting, which is fortunate because a prime ideal has no obvious (to me) generalization.
The intersection of all maximal congruences gives us a congruences that identifies precisely the things that cannot be distinguished by quotient algebras of the original algebra that are simple in much the same way that the Jacobson ring gives us everything that can't be distinguished from zero in a quotient ring that is a field.
Jacobson congruence, shockingly, returns zero hits on Google search at time of writing, but this concept seems straightforward enough that I figure it must have a name and must have been studied before.

Is there a Jacobson congruence?
Let me try to discourage everyone from defining
the Jacobson congruence of an algebraic structure
to be the intersection of all its maximal congruences.
Even for rings, this definition is wrong.
The Jacobson radical of a ring $R$ is the intersection
of maximal left ideals of $R$.
This definition is introduced
to describe the ideal of those elements
that annihilate every simple left $R$-module.
That is, if $R$ is a ring, then the
set of elements that act trivially (i.e., like $0$)
on every simple
$R$-module equals the intersection of the maximal
left ideals of $R$, and this is a 2-sided ideal
of $R$ called the Jacobson radical (usually written $J(R)$).
If instead you form the intersection of all maximal 2-sided ideals
of $R$, then you get the Brown-McCoy radical.
Therefore, it might be reasonable to call the intersection
of all maximal congruences of an algebraic structure
the Brown-McCoy congruence of the structure.
It is reasonable to consider the Frattini subgroup of a group to be the analog of the Jacobson radical of a ring.
That is, if $G$ is a group, then the
set of elements that act trivially (i.e., like $1$)
on every simple
$G$-set
equals the intersection of the maximal
subgroups of $G$, and this is a normal subgroup
of $G$ called the Frattini subgroup (usually written $\Phi(G)$).

The universal algebraic
formulation of the Frattini congruence was
first introduced and applied in the paper
E. W. Kiss, S. M. Vovsi,
Critical algebras and the Frattini congruence
Algebra Universalis 34 (1995), 336-344.
Let me define the Frattini congruence of
an algebra $\mathbf{A}$.
For a congruence $\theta$ of $\mathbf{A}$
and a subalgebra $\mathbf{S}$ of $\mathbf{A}$,
define the saturation
of $\mathbf{S}$ by $\theta$ (usually written $\mathbf{S}^{\theta}$)
to be the least subalgebra of $\mathbf{A}$ that contains
$\mathbf{S}$ and is a union of $\theta$-classes.
Equivalently, if $\nu\colon \mathbf{A}\to \mathbf{A}/\theta$
is the natural map, then the saturation of $\mathbf{S}$
by $\theta$ is $\mathbf{S}^{\theta} = \nu^{-1}(\nu(\mathbf{S}))$.
Let's say that $\mathbf{S}$ is saturated by
$\theta$ if $\mathbf{S}^{\theta}=\mathbf{S}$.
The Frattini congruence of $\mathbf{A}$ is the largest congruence
$\Phi(\mathbf{A})$ of $\mathbf{A}$ that saturates all maximal
proper subalgebras of $\mathbf{A}$.
When $\mathbf{A}$ is finitely generated
the Frattini congruence can be characterized
as the 'congruence of nongenerators'
in the following sense: $\Phi(\mathbf{A})$ is the largest congruence on $\mathbf{A}$ with the property that if $\mathbf{S}$ is any subalgebra
of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{S}^{\Phi(\mathbf{A})} = \mathbf{A}$,
then $\mathbf{S}=\mathbf{A}$. (This says that $\mathbf{A}$ cannot
be obtained from any proper subalgebra through saturation
by $\Phi(\mathbf{A})$, and that $\Phi(\mathbf{A})$ is the largest congruence of $\mathbf{A}$ with this property.)

Serves me right for thinking only in terms of commutative rings. I'm a bit confused by the second half of the answer, though; what's the relationship between the Frattini congruence and the intersection of all maximal congruences?

Let $\delta$ be the intersection of all maximal congruences of $A$. There is no general relationship between $\delta$ and $\Phi(A)$. ($\delta$ depends only on the congruences of $A$ while $\Phi(A)$ depends on the relationship between the congruences and the maximal subalgebras of $A$. You can alter the subalgebra structure of $A$ without affecting the congruences by just expanding $A$ by some subset of constants.)  But, if $A$ is finite and every maximal subalgebra of $A$ is a congruence class, one can show that $\delta \leq \Phi(A)$.

At least sometimes the intersection of all maximal congruences on an algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is the radical congruence of $\mathcal{A}$ - see e.g. the opening line of Section 3 in Marra/Spada, The dual adjunction between
MV-algebras and Tychonoff
spaces. However, the phrase "radical congruence" is also used in other ways - see e.g. Veldsman - so some care should be taken. I have not, sadly, seen "Jacobson congruence" used before, although it clearly fits and as Keith Kearnes points out in his answer the Jacobson radical only corresponds to the intersection of all maximal congruences in the setting of commutative rings.
(FWIW the quotient of $\mathcal{A}$ by the intersection of the maximal congruences of $\mathcal{A}$ is at least sometimes called the "cosocle" of $\mathcal{A}$, see Definition 2.2 of Kearnes/Marczak, $p_n$-sequences of algebras with one fundamental operation.)
